# Updating geometric value

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I'm using 'dat.gui' for user input and want the **tableBoardGeometry** and the **tableLegsGeometry** to update in my render method with the values from the input.

**Geometric declarations**

```
const boxWidth = 2; 
const boxHeight = 0.1; 
const boxDepth = 1;
const tableBoardGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

const tableLegPosition = (boxWidth * 0.45);
const tableLegHeight = 1.6
const tableLegHeightPosition = (tableLegHeight/2)
const tableLegsGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.05, tableLegHeight, 0.05);
```

**Dat.Gui**

```
     var gui = new dat.GUI();
     var controls = function() {
         this.TableWidth = 1;
         this.TableHeight = 1;
         this.LegsWidth = 1;
         this.LegsHeight = 1;
         this.RotationSpeed = 0.005;
    }
    var title = new controls();
        gui.add(title, 'RotationSpeed', 0.005, 0.1);
```

**Render Method**

```
    const render = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        tableBoard.rotation.y -= title.RotationSpeed;
        /* I'd like to update the Geomtrics here depending on user input */
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        orbitCamera()
     }
```

I've tried using:

```
tableBoard.scale.x = title.TableWidth;
```

and it doesnt work properly because of the variable dependencies for getting the right number. The variable that i'd like to update is **tableLegHeightPosition**

**edit:**
The issue is that the sub mesh follows the parent mesh on scaling

Comment: In this case, it's probably best to just recreate the box geometry with the new parameters. This is also done by the geometry browser of the official documentation (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry).

Comment: Any suggestion on how i can make the parent scale not effect the child?

Comment: TBH, there should only be a parent/child relationship if this effect is actually desired. If not, consider to place both objects to the same hierarchy level of your scene graph.

Comment: I do desire it though. I've built a table that is parent to the legs which makes the surface remain on top of the legs.
On the 'dat.gui' input of the surface it also changes the behaviour of the legs which is unwanted.
https://gyazo.com/c385d3770c88a7d59483a18421c202b0

Comment: (i want the the legs to remain the same size despite the adjustment of the surface)